# How to ensure calling of fallback method? How to call my method from another Bean?

Tags: spring, hystrix, fallback

My **fallback**  method **handleCitizenDown{}** is not executed by any means! I saw a solution I should write my method in another Bean but I don't understand how. My URL and other dependencies work fine just the method is not called when it is failed.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/id/{id}")
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "handleCitizenDown")
public ResponseEntity<VaccinationAndCitizenResponse>
        getAllCitizenListByCenterId(@PathVariable Integer id){

    VaccinationAndCitizenResponse citizenResponse = new VaccinationAndCitizenResponse();
    VaccinationCenter center = centerRepo.findById(id).get();
    citizenResponse.setCenter(center);
    List<CitizenModel> citizenModelList =
            restTemplate.getForObject("http://CITIZEN-SERVICE/citizen/id/"+id, List.class);
    citizenResponse.setCitizenModels(citizenModelList);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(citizenResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}


public ResponseEntity<VaccinationAndCitizenResponse> handleCitizenDown(@PathVariable Integer id){
    VaccinationAndCitizenResponse citizenResponse = new VaccinationAndCitizenResponse();
    VaccinationCenter center = centerRepo.findById(id).get();
    citizenResponse.setCenter(center);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(citizenResponse, HttpStatus.OK); }
```

[image]

Comment: what callback method do you mean ?  Also , can you post the codes to describe your problem rather than an image. thanks so much

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question is updated now with the code and attached image. Could you please suggest any solution? It is Fallback not Callback, sorry for my typo!